# Implementation of One-to-One relationship in Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am inexperienced programmer. I'd like to add one-to-one relationship CurrencyDefault (that value will be assigned to the field in FlaskForm) between User and Currency:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Sequence('user_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    pswd_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    expenses = db.relationship('Expense', backref='user')
    currency = db.relationship('Currency', backref='user')
    curr_default = ?

    # ...

class Currency(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Sequence('expense_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    abbr = db.Column(db.String(10))
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    default = ?

    # ...
```

What I want to achieve is to assign to each `user.id` one `currency.id` (one-to-one)

I'd like to ask for some advice what is the best way to make it.

After considering the problem I have some ideas like:

1. Association Table with uselist=False relationship,
2. Create a new class CurrencyDefault(id, user_id, currency_id),
3. Or maybe there is other, better way to achieve it?

I'm very curious of your point of view on this problem.

## Implementing solution:

This is how my classes look like now:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Sequence('user_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    pswd_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    currency_default_choice = db.Column(db.Integer, b.ForeignKey('currency.id'))
    expenses = db.relationship('Expense', backref='user')
    currency = db.relationship('Currency', backref='user', foreign_keys="Currency.user_id")
    # currency_default = db.relationship(
    #       'Currency',
    #       foreign_keys='User.currency_default_choice',
    #       backref='currency_default',
    #       uselist=False,
    # )

# ...

class Currency(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Sequence('expense_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    abbr = db.Column(db.String(10), b.ForeignKey('currency_official_abbr.abbr'))
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    currency_default = db.relationship(
            'User',
            foreign_keys='User.currency_default_choice',
            backref='currency_default',
            uselist=False,
    )
```

1. The first problem I find is that I can set `Currency.id` object created by `other_user` as `currency_default_choice`. How to restrict `currency_default_choice` only to the `<Currency>` that was created by this `user`?
2. What is the difference between setting relationship having `foreign key` in `User` class (`currency_default_choice = db.Column(db.Integer, b.ForeignKey('currency.id'))`) with:

```
class Currency(db.Model):
# ...
currency_default = db.relationship(
            'User',
            foreign_keys='User.currency_default_choice',
            backref='currency_default',
            uselist=False,
    )
```

and setting this relationship on `User` side with:

```
class User(db.Model):
# ...
    currency_default = db.relationship(
          'Currency',
          foreign_keys='User.currency_default_choice',
          backref='currency_default',
          uselist=False,
    )
```

Ad.2. What seems to me is that there is no difference between these two ways because the `backref` parameter implicates `bidirectional behavior` so it doesn't matter if I placed `db.relationship()` in `User` or `Currency` class. Is it correct?

3. Using Python shell I added value to the `User.currency_default`

```
>>> app = create_app()
>>> app.app_context().push()
>>> admin = User.query.filter_by(username='admin').first()
<User(id= 1, username = admin, email = admin@admin.com)
>>> currency = Currency.query.filter_by(user=admin)
>>> currency
<flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery object at 0x03EA05D0>
>>> currency[0].id
1
>>> admin.currency_default = currency[0]
>>> db.session.commit()
>>> currency[0].currency_default
<User(id= 1, username = admin, email = admin@admin.com)
>>> admin.currency_default_choice
1
```

and then using Admin Panel after running `flask run`  I wanted to remove introduced value but I got error that I don't understand. Why there is circular dependency between `(Currency.currency_default)`,`(User.currency_default)` and `(User.currency)`? I don't understand what is happening. How to fix it?

```
sqlalchemy.exc.CircularDependencyError: Circular dependency detected. 
(ProcessState(OneToManyDP(Currency.currency_default), 
<Currency at 0x46542b0>, delete=False), 
ProcessState(ManyToOneDP(User.currency_default), 
<User at 0x4669b10>, delete=False), 
SaveUpdateState(<Currency at 0x46542b0>), 
ProcessState(OneToManyDP(User.currency), <User at 0x4669b10>, delete=False), 
SaveUpdateState(<User at 0x4669b10>))
```

Comment: That sounds like a many-to-one relationship.  (Many `Users` share the same `Currency` choice. .  So there would be a `currency_id` within the `User` model.

Comment: No, it's one-to-one because each `user` can create his own `Currency` with unique ID and has access only to currencies that was created by him.

Comment: `uselist=False` is the usual way then-- there's an example on the SQLAlchemy for the setup https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-one . I would store the default on the user-side, as it would be clearer (user.default_currency_choice), save a little space, and save a query to work out the default each time.